# Need to use docker-compose to build but but not run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker compose file:

```
name: polyocr
services:
  web-prebuild: 
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./deployment/docker/web/Dockerfile.prebuild
    
      
  web:
    build: 
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./deployment/docker/web/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - web-prebuild
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
```

It works for me, however, I don't need the "pre-build" docker to run. I just need it to be built before I start the other one.
Is there a way for me to get docker-compose up to build all, but run only the web?
Thanks

Comment: maybe you can solve it with a single (multi-stage) dockerfile

Comment: If the "prebuild" container doesn't need to run, why does it need to be built?  What would happen if you just deleted it from the Compose file?

Comment: Throwing down the prebuild is possible. The thing is, the prebuild is changed rairly, while the web changes often. I plan on running the build in bitbucket pipelines, so my plan is to pull the prebuilt image, and than run the build. This will save most of the "apt-get"s and "pip install"s, and get me a better time to deploy scheme.

Comment: @DavidMaze, to be honest - it really is not that usefull. I can make sure I build it whenever I need, and ignore it when I don't. I just really wanted life to be as easy as possible for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with `docker-compose`. There are some workarounds described in [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4744) and [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4489) issue, but it cannot be solved using `docker-compose`.

Comment: In the end, I just set the CMD to be "echo hello", that kinda closes this prebuild fast. It's not the best solution, but it does work